# Probability of one followed by another

Tags: probability

I am working on my homework and have been stuck on this problem for two hours:

There are 39 chocolates in a box, all identically shaped. There are 16 filled with nuts, 13 with caramel and 10 are solid chocolate. You randomly select one piece, eat it, and then select a second piece. Find the probability of selecting a solid chocolate, followed by a caramel chocolate. Write your answer as a fraction in the form *a/b*.

I do have the answer, it's *130/1482*, or *5/57*, however I don't know how this answer was made.

An explanation on how to do this would be very much appreciated. Unfortunately my teacher doesn't provide formulas for what we learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know there are $39$ chocolates total. $10$ of these are solid chocolate, and thus the probability of your first piece being solid is $10/39$.

Afterwards, we know $38$ chocolates remain, $13$ of which are caramel. Thus, there is a $13/38$ probability to pick caramel the second time.

Therefore, the probability you seek is the product of these two since you did them in sequence, and that yields

$$\frac{10}{39} \cdot \frac{13}{38} = \frac{130}{1482} = \frac{5}{57}$$

---

An equivalent way to work this out, if the above doesn't feel quite intuitive to you, is this... In how many ways can you pick a chocolate, have it be solid, then pick another, and have it be caramel? That answer is $13 \cdot 10$ since you have $13$ choices for one, and $10$ for the other.

Then consider how many ways in which you could pick two chocolates - in general, with no restrictions. That would be $39 \cdot 38$, since you have $39$ to start with, and then $38$ since you took one away.

We know that

$$\text{probability of an event} = \frac{\text{# of ways that event can occur}}{\text{# of total possible events}}$$

Therefore, the probability you seek is

$$\frac{13 \cdot 10}{39 \cdot 38}$$

which gives our answer from before.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- What is the probability that the first piece is solid chocolate?
- Given that the first piece was solid chocolate, what are the remaining $38$ pieces?
- Given that the first piece was solid chocolate, what is the probability that the second piece is caramel chocolate?
- Combining these results, what is the joint probability that the first piece is solid chocolate and the second piece is caramel chocolate?